# Get access to a component from other activity (Kotlin with Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following problem: I would like to access the component (linearLayout4) of another activity from one activity.

As you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKwrG.png), the LinearLayout4 is not found because it is in another activity.

How can I access LinearLayout4?
Thanks in advance!
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually access that same instance of the view from another activity, however you can get that view from another activity's layout using layout inflater:

```kotlin
val firstActivityView = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_1,binding.cont,false)
```

Here you'll get the whole layout of first activity and then you can call

> firstActivityView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout4)